# Is there a bandwitdh limitation using all USB-ports on my computer?

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop, mouse

I have a seemingly old Asus UX32VD, however this PC did the job for office.
I have connected these USB devices to my laptop:

- USB-Port#1: USB-Hub with a headphone, receiver for my mouse and a USB-lamp
- USB-Port#2: receiver for my keyboard
- USB-Port#3: USB-graphic adapter to use a thrid 1080p monitor

All ports support USB 3.0.
My problem is that from time to time I recognize huge lags and slowdowns in keyboard and mouse inputs that further working is not possible. 
Could there just be an issue with funk reivers or can there be some bandwith problems?
How can I best test or see how much bandwith is used for the USB-lanes?

Comment: If there was a USB resource problem Windows would report that was the case.  The latency just sounds like processing latency,

Comment: May there be the option that I can priorize the mouse and keyboard?

Comment: I would verify you don't have any cordless phones running at 2.4 GHz, since most keyboard/mice recovers run at that frequency, unless they are Bluetooth.

Comment: While not conclusive, on a similar laptop, I've noticed a wireless mouse freezing while copying data from a USB device to HDD, and the issue stopped after transfer completed. Likely, it's CPU or I/O limitations on the old laptop. Just be aware of the issue, or get another PC.

Comment: *"...can there be some bandwith problems?"* -- Depends on how many USB host controllers your laptop has.  There could be just a single USB host controller and an embedded hub to provide the three ports.  The existence of 3 USB ports rarely means that there are 3 USB host controllers.

Comment: Most likely you have an interference between 2400 MHz wireless receivers for your HID devices with USB 3.0 SS operations. Try to distance the receivers from your system using USB extenders.